# Convert IP address in C

Tags: c, ip, ip-address

I have:

```
192.168.1.1
```

How can I convert it?

I have tried splitting the ip address with sscanf like:

```
sscanf(hostaddress,"%d.%d.%d.%d", &d1, &d2, &d3, &d4);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have an IP address [...] How can I convert it to a long?

You'e looking for the function [`inet_pton(3)`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/inet_ntop.html).

```
unsigned char buf[sizeof(struct in_addr)]
rc = inet_pton(AF_INET, "192.168.1.1", buf);
```

And `rc` should be 1 for success. A return code of 0 or -1 means error.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`inet_addr`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738563%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

```
unsigned long addr = inet_addr("192.168.1.1");
```